# Facebook user news feed/unique user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Im developing an ios app with facebook integration, I want to display the news feed of a single user, like if it is a group page, but public feed of a user. Is there a way to make an automatic login for that specific user?? I mean with no interface and no questions and no way to change that user login. I`ve already achieved to display a public group feed in a tableview via the graph api and all that. Is just my University career manager have a facebook user as the main career page instead of a open group, I know is silly but I cant do anything about that. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. What you means by 'automatic login'? 
2. Did you know about what is access token?

Comment: I mean I dont want to have a usual login for every user and all that, only one user only one source for the app at the startup. About the access token Ill get it of that single user

Comment: Something like a predetermined login, but the app user cant change that session.